# node e2e tests with selenium : how to set Chrome a selenium browser?

Tags: node.js, selenium, macos-sierra

**Environment :

OSX Sierra 10.12.6 default Browser safari / Node v8.4.0 / Chrome Canary 60.0.3112.101**

I am trying to test my environment , using selenium .. but :
- Safari is starting , need to start Chrome as selenium browser
- get the error :

```
> node test/e2e/runner.js

> Starting dev server...

Starting to optimize CSS...
> Listening at http://localhost:8080

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  32583

[Test] Test Suite
=====================

Running:  default e2e tests

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ value: 
   { stacktrace: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

thanks for feedback

**test/e2e. files **

**runner.js**

```
// 1. start the dev server using production config
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'testing'
var server = require('../../build/dev-server.js')

server.ready.then(() => {
  // 2. run the nightwatch test suite against it
  // to run in additional browsers:
  //    1. add an entry in test/e2e/nightwatch.conf.json under "test_settings"
  //    2. add it to the --env flag below
  // or override the environment flag, for example: `npm run e2e -- --env chrome,firefox`
  // For more information on Nightwatch's config file, see
  // http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file
  var opts = process.argv.slice(2)
  if (opts.indexOf('--config') === -1) {
    opts = opts.concat(['--config', 'test/e2e/nightwatch.conf.js'])
  }
  if (opts.indexOf('--env') === -1) {
    opts = opts.concat(['--env', 'chrome'])
  }

  var spawn = require('cross-spawn')
  var runner = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch', opts, { stdio: 'inherit' })

  runner.on('exit', function (code) {
    server.close()
    process.exit(code)
  })

  runner.on('error', function (err) {
    server.close()
    throw err
  })
})
```

**night watch.conf.js**

```
require('babel-register')
var config = require('../../config')

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || config.dev.port)
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**selenium-debug.log**

```
15:21:02.882 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068'
15:21:02.883 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-08-24 15:21:03.095:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2678ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
15:21:03.426 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
15:21:03.788 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
15:21:03.789 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
15:21:04.032 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
2017-08-24 15:21:04.274:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2017-08-24 15:21:04.412:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3632be31{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2017-08-24 15:21:04.450:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3632be31{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-08-24 15:21:04.651:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@32709393{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-08-24 15:21:04.652:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @4235ms
15:21:04.653 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
2017-08-24 15:21:07.820:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp1562557367-10: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-39aeed2f: Initialising WebDriverServlet
15:21:08.910 INFO - Binding default provider to: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService
15:21:08.911 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.BeginSession@1e79c820
15:21:08.936 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
15:21:09.058 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Test, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, }
15:21:09.060 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Test, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
15:21:09.087 INFO - Capabilities {acceptSslCerts=true, name=Test, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b) on port 2776
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Comment: How have you installed chrome? using brew or directly? Also how is chromedriver setup?

Comment: yes .. I found the issue and how to solve it... I'll write the answer soon..
basically I am using Chrome Canary !!! and default Is Chrome.. so I need to update my night watch.conf .js.  The chrome driver is set with nom ( chromedriver: "^2.27.2)  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check which Chrome version I was using for dev!  Chrome canary and not Chrome, so I need to update my night watch.conf.js accordingingly

```
test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || config.dev.port)
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chromeCanary',
        platform: 'MAC',
        chromeOptions: {
          binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary',
        },
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    }
  }
```

then I can run the e2e tests:

```
> node test/e2e/runner.js

> Starting dev server...

Starting to optimize CSS...
> Listening at http://localhost:8080

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  36140

[Test] Test Suite
=====================

Running:  default e2e tests
 ✔ Element <#app> was visible after 185 milliseconds.
 ✔ Testing if element <h1> contains text: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App".
 ✔ Testing if element <img> has count: 1

OK. 3 assertions passed. (16.735s)
```